# Solve $XA + A^T = I$ for $X$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I want to solve

$$X \cdot A + A^T = I$$

for $X$, $A$ and $X$ are arbitrary matrices and $A$ is invertible. I know that $A \cdot A^{-1} = I$, this helps, but I don't know how to deal with the additional $+A^T$.

How can I approach this?

Comment: Did you mean "$A$ is invertible" in your hypothesis instead of "$X$ is invertible"?

Comment: Yes, sorry for the typo; $A$ is invertible

Comment: @Mahoni, solutions remains the same, false assumption that I made before was that A must be invertible to solve it

Answer (score 3):

Rewrite $X\cdot A+A^T=I$ as $X\cdot A=I-A^T$ and premultiply, since $A$ is invertible, by $A^{-1}$ on he right to get
$$X\cdot A\cdot A^{-1}=(I-A^T)A^{-1}.$$
Thus, this gives
$$X=(I-A^T)A^{-1}=A^{-1}-A^T\cdot A^{-1}.$$

Comment: Not true. e.g. $$A = \left(\begin{array}{cc}1 & i\\0 & 0 \end{array}\right)$$ and $$X = \left(\begin{array}{cc}0 & 1 \\ -i & 0\end{array}\right)$$. Every 2x2 counter-example is complex, though.

Comment: @Hurkyl, thank you for the note

Answer (score 2):

multiply both sides by $ A^{-1} $ so you get

$ X+ A^{T}\cdot A^{-1}=A^{-1} $ and you get your final result.